# How to calculate X-axis reduction when view is rotated along Y-axis

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, trigonometry

How do I find out the X axis reduction when a view is rotated along the Y-axis?

Im trying to create a folding animation using a combination of rotation and translation.

I have 2 TextViews sitting side-by-side each other as shown by the xml below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/colorBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="A"
        android:textSize="100sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="B"
        android:textSize="100sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The way I am planning to achieve my folding animation is by rotating the Left and Right textview simultaneously while translating the right textView to the left. I achieve that using the code below:

```
left.setPivotX(0f);
left.setPivotY(left.getHeight()/2);
right.setPivotX(right.getWidth());
right.setPivotY(right.getHeight()/2);

ObjectAnimator rotateLeft;
rotateLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(left, "rotationY", left.getRotationY(), 45.0f);
ObjectAnimator rotateRight;
rotateRight = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(right, "rotationY", right.getRotationY(), -45.0f);
ObjectAnimator translateRightX;
translateRightX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(right, "x", right.getX()-amountOfXToTranslate);

animateSet = new AnimatorSet();
animateSet.play(rotateRight).with(rotateLeft).with(translateRightX);
animateSet.setDuration(3000);
animateSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animateSet.start();
```

My question here is how do i calculate the value of `amountOfXToTranslate`?

I have tried various mathematical calculation.

Method 1: Based on the reasoning that when a view is rotated by 90 degrees, the width is 0 and it disappears completely and also when a view is not rotated at all (0 degree rotation) the width is at its max.  I made the assumption that when it is rotated by 45 degrees, its width along the X-axis should be half of its maximum width. So in this case, going by this logic, given that I have 2 textviews that is 150dp wide each, when both of them are at an angle of 45 degrees, the amount of space between the 2 views will be (150/2)*2. So `amountOfXToTranslate` will be 150.

Upon testing this, my assumption proved to be wrong. For some reason, this formula works for some sizes and fails miserably for others. (eg: When both the textview is of width 100dp and I do a 100dp translation, the animation looks fine and there is no gap between the 2 views. But when they are 150dp wide each, there will be a gap. So the formula appears to work for widths less than 150dp)

Method 2: So with the failure of method 1, i decided to use real mathematical approach and consider this in a 3 dimensional plane. Using the basic maths that we were taught in high school, the trigonometric functions:
http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/Images/BackGround/SinCos.gif
I figured that I can calculate the value of `amountOfXToTranslate` using the formula of `AC = AB cos 45` (AC and AB is based on the image from the attached link). So my final formula to calculate the amount of X to translate is `(widthOfTextView * cos 45) * 2`. Unfortunately, after trying this formula, it still isnt correct and the amount of X translation falls short, leaving a gap between the 2 views.

Below are some images of my problem and attemps: http://i41.tinypic.com/20z8d4o.png, http://i41.tinypic.com/2hmkbj4.png, http://i40.tinypic.com/k12xbq.png

So how do i find the value of `amountOfXToTranslate`?

The question is partially related to [How do I calculate the height of the bottom edge when rotating a plane on the x-axis in 3d space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835111/how-do-i-calculate-the-height-of-the-bottom-edge-when-rotating-a-plane-on-the-x) but oddly the reverse equation does not work (method 2).

EDITTED
Well, i decided to do some manual investigative work and the results is just mind boggling.
The following test results have been carried out with a constant view height of 150dp and rotation along the Y-axis of 45 degrees.
Result 1: When width of each view is 150px, the translation needed to close the gap between the 2 views after rotation is 120px
Result 2: When width of each view is 300px, the translation needed to close the gap between the 2 views after rotation is 290px
Result 3: When width of each view is 450px, the translation needed to close the gap between the 2 views after rotation is 490px
Result 4: When width of each view is 600px, the translation needed to close the gap between the 2 views after rotation is 712px

I just find it weird that when the width of each view is less than 300, the amount of translation needed is less than the width of a single view. BUT, when the width of each view is more than 300, the amount of translation needed is bigger than the width of a single view.